# Team Foundation Server Work items

Tags: tfs

I recently re-installed Team Foundation Server and now no one can change the state of work items (remotely).
For Example, I have a User, this user can remote desktop to the Server and open Visual Studio, then he can change the state of work items, but if his laptop's visual studio is connected to the server's tfs then He can't change the state, he can only see the state of the work item.

Before I had to re-install everything worked fine and the users could change the state as they go on with the projects

Comment: Did the reinstall change the permissions for the users?  The default setting might be that they can't change the state.

Comment: What version of TFS, what version of Visual Studio, and what error do you get when you try to change the state?

Comment: Are the logins different between using the visual studio client remoted into the server versus on their own desktop?

Comment: I can't even change the state, meaning there is no dropdown to select a new state( no errors are shown ), the logins are exactly the same as the previous time.
Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2012. I think it is client side because when I connect with my new laptop it works perfectly

Comment: If they can connect to TFS and see the WorkItems, they have at least the read permissions. Could you please check the WorkItemTypeDefinition, especially the transitions between the states if they have defined the value "for" or "not". Usually states are invisible when the transition is prohibited for you. I guess the group memberships or the WorkItemTypeDefinitions got lost during the re-install.